# how to use zinit with zsh? Append or make a new file?

Tags: zsh

I'd like to use zinit with zsh. But where should I put my configuration?

These are at the bottom of ‘.zshrc’ file:

```
source "$HOME/.zinit/bin/zinit.zsh"
autoload -Uz _zinit
(( ${+_comps} )) && _comps[zinit]=_zinit
### End of Zinit's installer chunk
```

Do I need to create a new file or put my configuration below these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you put it below that, like this and this works.

```sh
### End of Zinit's installer chunk

zinit ice wait'!' lucid nocd atload'!tw_setup'
zinit light reobin/typewritten

zinit as"program" make'!' atclone'./direnv hook zsh > zhook.zsh' \
  atpull'%atclone' pick"direnv" src"zhook.zsh" for \
    direnv/direnv

zinit as"program" \
  mv"bin/scd* -> scd" \
  pick"scd" \
  src"shellrcfiles/zshrc_scd" \
  for pavoljuhas/smart-change-directory

zinit snippet OMZL::history.zsh
zinit snippet OMZP::colored-man-pages

zinit for ext-git zsh-users+fast
```